# Prometheus Absent function

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

I want to check if a certain metric is not available in prometheus for 5 minute.

I am using `absent(K_KA_GCPP)` and giving a 5 minute threshold. But it seems I cannot group the absent function on certain labels like Site Id.

Absent works if the metric is not available for all 4 site Ids. I want to find out if the metric is not available or absent for 1 site id out of all 4 and I don't want to hardcode the site Id labels in the query, it should be generic.  Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: No. I am using absent and hardcoding my site ids now.

Comment: I'm doing the same, the only other way I found to do absent on up was to do an alert on up{metric} == 0 with a time a 30secondes or less to launch the alert on first call

Answer (score 6):

I was able to achieve this by doing something like this:

```
count(up{job="prometheus"} offset 1h) by (project) unless count(up{job="prometheus"} ) by (project)
```

If the metric is missing in the last 1 hour, it will trigger an alert.
You can add any labels you need after the `by` section (that's helpful in altering for example).

Source: [Prometheus Alert for missing metrics and labels](https://medium.com/@niravshah2705/prometheus-alert-for-missing-metrics-and-labels-afd4b8f12b1)

Answer (score 2):

The `offset` I feel like is a great starting point, but it has a big weakness. If there's no sample in the `time - offset` then your query doesn't return what you'd like to.

I reworked the answer from Ahmed to this:

```
group(present_over_time(myMetric{label1="asd"}[3h])) by (labels) unless group(myMetric{label1="asd"}) by (labels)
```

- using period with `present_over_time` should fix that aforementioned problem
- `group()` aggregation, since you don't need the value
- also I like to use the actual metric, since `up{}` is a state of the scraped target, not the "metric is present" information which I feel might not be equivalent

Comment: +1 @strudelPi. The only thing I modified - I extended 3h window (I made it 48h for my alert), cause this window defines how long your expression will be detecting the problem. If metric is still missing for a period of time more than this window length, expression will stop producing the outcome you rely on.
`(group(present_over_time(st_Worker_Queue_Size_Max{deployment="worker"}[48h])) by (deployment, namespace)) unless group(st_Worker_Queue_Size_Max{deployment="worker"}) by (deployment, namespace)`

Answer (score 1):

There exists the Prometheus [absent_over_time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#absent_over_time) function

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as a group! see how to [configure an alert rule group](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/data-configuration/agent/agent_monitoring/#configure-an-alert-rule-group)

[image]

You can also use `absent_over_time` function

[image]

absent returns just one result as it is for a single site ID in your case

```
 absent(<expr>)
```

Returns an empty vector if the vector passed to it has any elements and a 1-element vector with the value 1 if the vector passed to it has no elements. This is useful for alerting on when no time series exist for a given metric name and label combination.